# Geometry problem with two chords originating from a common point outside the circle.

Tags: geometry

[image: problem figure]

This one's got me pulling my hair.

Comment: Try [this](http://www.mathopenref.com/secantsintersecting.html)

Comment: Or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point)

Answer (score 0):

By the power-of-a-point theorem,

$$OA\cdot OB=OP\cdot OQ.$$

Answer (score -1):

**Construction:** Join BQ and AP

**Proof**

$1. \angle BQO=\angle PAO$(Angle subtended betwewn a chord and a tangent is equal to the angle subtended by the chord on its alternate segment),

$2.\angle QBO=\angle OPA$(Angle subtended betwewn a chord and a tangent is equal to the angle subtended by the chord on its alternate segment)

SO THEY ARE SIMILAR

$\frac{AO}{OQ}=\frac{OP}{OB}$

$\frac {AO}{12}=\frac {4}{18}$

Solve it to get value of AO.